Azure DevOps Build Validation from Pipeline in another repository
I have 2 Repositories

Repo A: Application Code Repo
Repo B: DevOps Repo

All the build and release pipelines are in Repo B.
I am trying to achieve here is Build validation
So whenever I raise a PR from feature branch to master branch of Repo A that time Build validation pipeline which is in Repo B will trigger and pass the check (Which I am defining in branch policy).
It's working fine in same repo but with two repositories I am not getting any solution also I have 3 branch in Repo A and I have to implement for all the three branches.


So, whenever I raise a PR from feature branch to master branch of Repo A that time Build validation pipeline which is in Repo B will trigger and pass the check (Which I am defining in branch policy).

I tested the issue, and it works when the Repo A and Repo B is in the same project.
My test:

Repo A and Repo B is in the same project.
Create a pipeline named build and release pipelines in Repo B

Set Build validation branch policy with the pipeline in Repo B for main branch of Repo A

Create a pull request from feature branch to main branch in Repo A, the Build validation pipeline is triggered and successful.



Actually Triggers were not working. So I created the pipeline again and now its working as expected. Sometimes it happens with the triggers. THanks for the response.
